# Using DBpedia for book search

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to write code to query DBpedia and search for book information like author, book title, etc..

What is the prefix and which Named Graph should I use to build this SPARQL query?

Answer (score 4):

an example query could look like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?s  ?author 
where {
?s rdf:type ontology:Book;
  ontology:author ?author .
}
```

you can test it on http://dbpedia.org/sparql
and the default graph is http://dbpedia.org

you might also need to take a look at http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Book for the book class properties